# How to upgrade from loki to juno?

Tags: release-juno, system

I have elementary OS version loki installed on a computer. I want to upgrade it to juno . How do I get juno without losing the apps i have installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no I am afraid, you will need to perform a clean install. Download Juno from here, [https://elementary.io](https://elementary.io/). Don't forget to backup your data.

Comment: Isn't there any way to upgrade things manually?

Comment: That is not suggested, user can end up with a broken system. Best choice is to back-up your data and perform  a clean install.